# Spring Thymeleaf route users to /users/{thisUser}/thisUsersCollectionOfThings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send a user to a particular page containing a list of their items.  So far I've been somewhat unsuccessful.

I first display a page listing all users, with hyperlinks scooting off to, what I think should be their respective page.

In my template I have this:

```
    <li th:each="key: ${users.keySet()}">
        <span th:text="${users.get(key).getName()}"></span>
        <a href="games.html" th:href="@{/{user}/games (user=${users.get(key).getName()}) }">View games</a></li>
    </li>
```

which does currently route to the urls of `http://localhost:8080/Steve/games` for example.

The difficulty I'm having is knowing how to tie the rest together.

I have a Controller with this mapping that I believe should be called when this URL is

```
    @RequestMapping("/{users}/games")
    @ResponseBody
    public String userGames(@PathVariable final String username,
                            Model model){
        .. List<Games> games= getGames(username)..
        model.addAttribute("games", games);
        return "games";
    }
```

so what I'd like to do there is display the 'games' template html page but with the list of games that I've retrieved for that user.  However I'm getting the standard `This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.` error and I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

My 'Games' template follows the same pattern as previous by looping through a list:

```
 <ol>
    <li th:each="game : ${games}" th:text="${game.getName()}"></li>
</ol>
```

but is not displayed.

My Game class has the method for name retrieval.  There are no exceptions thrown in the stack trace

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have method getName() in your Game class? Does anything (stacktrace) show up in java console?

Comment: You could check with ${game.name} instead.

Comment: @mate00 - Hi, yes the method exists, no stack trace of use tbh.  No exceptions etc.I'll try the game.name and see if that helps!

Comment: @mate00 - game.name gave the same result.

Comment: Is it possible that you share your project? I could try to run it myself and see if I can help.

Comment: @mate00 - possibly, I'd need to tidy it up some first and make it somewhat resentabl e :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191221/discussion-between-mate00-and-null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to summarize our talk on a chat: your controller class was missing a `@Controller` annotation so your mapping method wasn't called at all. Then you make sure the string in the controller method param is the same name as what is being passed through.